# What is the precision of std::erf?

Tags: math, c++11, precision, double-precision

C++11 introduced very useful math functions in the standard like [erf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf) and [erfc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erfc). There are mentions about "guaranteed underflow" for inputs greater or smaller than certain values, but I don't know enough about floating point representation to understand clearly what this means in terms of precision.

If this question makes sense; what precision (order of magnitude at least) can I expect from the approximation implemented by the standard library (if it is specified)?

Comment: It's not specified.  I believe a conforming C++ implementation is permitted to say `42.0` when asked for the sine of one radian.  However, in practice, you can assume that double-precision `erf` is faithfully rounded---you will get one of the two floating-point numbers closest to the erf of the number you fed it.

Comment: @tmyklebu I would like to believe you, but assuming I would get that number means that the standard implementation has at least 17 decimal digits precision. I do admire and trust the vendors of the C++ compilers I use (gcc and clang), but this seems like an unreasonable assumption to me, considering that most of the approximations I found don't go higher than 7 decimal digits precision. Not that I am complaining; I do expect it to be a rather crude approximation, I simply wish I could know how crude.

Comment: You cannot measure the precision of a function like this in "digits" unless it's a very poor approximation.  Being correct to 17 digits yet returning a `double` is impossible to achieve even for the function `x/3`; consider the input `29`.  There is no "standard implementation" in the sense of "standard C++," but the one in glibc is faithfully-rounded and I'd expect Apple did just as well.  I have not examined fdlibm's `erf`/`erfc`, if it even has them.

Comment: glibc's `erf` and `erfc` actually came from fdlibm, so fdlibm's `erf` and `erfc` are faithfully-rounded as well.

Comment: FYI: I tested the standard implementation for uniform values in (-5, 5) against the python multiprecision library mpmath and actually it seems to be both fast and very accurate! I'm pleasantly surprised :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the quality of the implementation, which is up to the vendor of the compiler (or runtime libraries, if acquired separately). In the best case, the precision will match the precision of the specific type you use (double, long double, and so on).

Notice that the precision of the returned value is not related to the guaranteed underflow. This is just an enforced postcondition that assures the return value is the [special underflow FP value](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/premk/archive/2006/02/25/539198.aspx) if the input is outside the expected domain.

Comment: I find it not very nice from the standard to not guarantee a minimum precision; it makes it difficult to rely on these functions for numerical processing. But thank you, this answers my question :)

Comment: Yes, that would make life a lot easier. The problem is that for the functions that depend on trigonometric operations that's hard to achieve because the higher the precision, the more computation time involved. If you have a coprocessor that does these operations, your precision is also affected by its precision, and so on. So it's really hard to reach a standard here, especially for a large commitee, and even harder to be compliant to it.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: While the language standards don't require any particular accuracy for specific math functions, the vendor of the library may provide information on the maximum error of the implementation, either stated as absolute error, relative error, or [ulp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), so check the documentation. Robust math libraries typically provide results with a few (single-digit) ulps of error for `erf()` and `erfc()`.

Comment: There is no "special underflow FP value."  On a good implementation, you will get 0 and an underflow flag if `erf` or `erfc` computes a value closer to zero than the smallest subnormal floating-point number.