# What is the accuracy of erf in Visual Studio MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to use the `erf` function in my code, and a standard implementation is included in `<cmath>`. It's important for me to know the accuracy of the result. Does anyone know how it is implemented there (what algorithm or approximation)?

I'm using Visual Studio if that makes a difference.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28028464/509868), since I want to know the precision of the implementation I'm using (MS Visual Studio), and the related question only says that the answer is implementation-specific.

Comment: It shall be implemented to satisfy the C++ specification. This question seems a bit broad. Please refer to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf) and then ask about specific points in separate questions so that we can end up with good questions and answers.

Comment: The only thing C++ says about std::erf is: _"[library.c]/1 The C ++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety."_. So this is more a C quiestion than a C++ one.

Comment: I'm asking about the specific implementation. There are several algorithms and approximations to achieve this

Comment: Did you already try the things from the `Error handling` section of documentation? Do you have any reason to expect a result that's further off than the unavoidable floating point rounding error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the precision of std::erf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028464/what-is-the-precision-of-stderf)

Comment: @keith doesn't look like the right duplicate, since this is mostly about the out-of-range specification (underflow) and not really about the in-range precision.

Comment: @grek40, how does "accuracy of result" in this question and "precision" in the other question differ? The poster of the other question says that documentation mentions "guarenteed underflow", but he actually clarifies this is not what he wants; he wants information about precision. The answers relate to precision and also answer this question.

Comment: This is really issue of the platform-stndard C library. On Linux with glibc there is published table for all functions: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html  Not sure how it looks like on Windows/VC++

Comment: @Keith That's not duplicate, since the cited answer states "it's implementation dependent" and this question is for a specific implementation.

Comment: You need to make it clearer that you are looking for a specific implementation rather than burying it as an afterthought. For example, the title is "in C++" rather than "in MSVC."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking specifically for MSVC implementation-defined behavior, the place to go is the [MSVC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/floating-point-support):

> These functions are implemented to balance performance with correctness. Because producing the correctly rounded result may be prohibitively expensive, these functions are designed to efficiently produce a close approximation to the correctly rounded result. In most cases, **the result produced is within +/-1 ulp of the correctly rounded result**, though there may be cases where there is greater inaccuracy.

Comment: So we are down to the guessing game, whether `erf` is part of the *"cases where there is greater inaccuracy"*? Or do they somehow explain a documentation guideline that those cases are made explicit somewhere? Good finding anyway.

Comment: I think these "cases" are more about values than functions. That is, for every mathematical function they checked 1000000 (or more) values and found no +/-2 inaccuracy, but never checked the whole domain (which would be around 2^64 values).

Comment: @anatolyg no, for some functions they actually documented inaccuracy... like for `sin`, `cos` and similars they write: *"If x is greater than or equal to 263, or less than or equal to -263, a loss of significance in the result [...]"*. So, the thing that remains unclear is, whether they documented such effects whenever they occur or if there is a possibility of undocumented inaccuracy.

Comment: I guess this is as good an answer as I'm likely to get. Doesn't look like they publish which method they use anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The solution might be not to use the `cmath` version (Visual Studio probably doesn't disclose the internal implementation), but to rely on an implementation that gives you the required information:

For example [Boost Error Functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_erf/error_function.html), there might be other open source implementations.

The boost implementation comes with an **Accuracy** table that lists the accuracy for a few implementations and on top of it, you might actually be able to have a look at the source code if the provided information is not enough.

Comment: I'd rather use something in the standard library and not resort to linking boost for just one function. I really just want to know what algorithm is used by MSVC for this

Comment: @EyalK. Well since MSDN doesn't give away specific information about accuracy, your options are somewhat limited. My answer is basically, if you need in-depth information about an implementation, then you have to use an open source implementation or at least one that documents everything you want to know. I guess you wouldn't be happy if I suggest you start working in a very specific department of Microsoft in order to have a look at their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using an arbitrary precision library as a golden reference one can easily generate an accurate characterization of the maximum error of a single-argument math function in *single precision* in minutes. I used a library that I have used for the past thirty years: Brent's MP from 1978. I would not recommend this for new development.

The largest error I found in MSVC 2019 (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29112) for `erff()` is 3.98346 ulps at `1.44902849f (0x1.72f388p+0)`. For *double precision*, exhaustive testing is not yet feasible. But one can certainly get a quick *impression* simply by invoking the function under test with many random arguments. In this fashion I found a maximum error of 3.98213 ulps in the `erf()` implementation of MSVC 2019 for an argument of `1.4761501386374922 (0x1.79e4f9b96f13cp+0)`.

Brian Gladman, Vincenzo Innocente and Paul Zimmermann, *Accuracy of Mathematical Functions in Single, Double, Double Extended, and Quadruple Precision*, [hal-03141101v5](https://inria.hal.science/hal-03141101), September 21, 2023

is work in progress that currently provides accuracy tracking for all major math libraries, including the math library used by MSVC 2022. The authors report the maximum error in single-precision `erff()`, based on exhaustive testing, as <= 3.99 ulps, which jibes with my findings for MSVC 2019. To find the maximum error of double-precision functions, they use a fairly sophisticated search heuristic which is superior to simple random search. With this they identified a maximum error in `erf()` of <= 4.62 ulps at `0x1.755dca4d8b458p+0`. Using this particular input of `1.4584623755756834 (0x1.755dca4d8b458p+0)` with MSVC 2019, I determined the error to be 4.61892 ulps.